# convert asp.net textbox string value to datetime in the insertitemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime

I am getting an cast exception when my formview attempts an insert of a record that has a string date that needs to go into a datetime column in SQL Server.
The field is bound to the table column using the Bind method, and is a part of the InsertItemTemplate of the FormView.
I am not sure how to convert the string to datetime during the insert. I thought maybe using the Insert Command to Convert(datetime, @PDate, 101)? That did not take care of the problem.

Please tell me what you think. I appreciate any help and suggestions.

****EDIT ****

This is the code for setting the current date

```
Protected Sub FormView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormView1.DataBound
    If FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert Then
        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb = FormView1.FindControl("textPDate")
        tb.Text = FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, DateFormat.ShortDate).ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the markup for the textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textPDate" runat="server" Style="position:absolute; top: 140px; left:181px; width: 200px;" 
            Text='<%# Bind("PDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This is some other calc I do during for inserting

```
Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewInsertEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemInserting
    Dim paper As New DropDownList
    Dim cylinder As New DropDownList
    Dim blockcode As New TextBox

    paper = FormView1.FindControl("dropdownPaperItem")
    cylinder = FormView1.FindControl("dropdownCylinderNumber")
    blockcode = FormView1.FindControl("textBlockCode")
    Dim c As New Common
    blockcode.Text = c.CalcBlockCode(paper.Text, cylinder.Text)

End Sub
```

I thought maybe I could cast the string to datetime in the ItemInserting event but I am not sure.

Comment: What is the format of your string ? Parse your string to `DateTime` object and then attach it as parameter to your Insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact format (`dd/MM/yyyy` in this example) you want to support, then use `TryParseExact`, like this:

```
Dim dt As DateTime

DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

Then you can check to see if `dt` is null or not after the `TryParseExact()` call, like this:

```
If Not dt Is Nothing
    ' Text box text is a valid date, pass the date to the database
End If
```

You can use this logic inside of the form view's item inserting event, like this:

```
Sub FormView1_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewInsertEventArgs)
    Dim dt As DateTime

    DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)

    If dt Is Nothing
        ' Use the Cancel property to cancel the insert operation.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand. Looks good. What event then would I intercept to parse and pass to the database?

Comment: @Ryan - I would assume this logic is tied to a button on the UI, right? If so, then put this logic into the button click event handler, see updated answer.

Comment: Basically, when a user opens the web page and the Formview loads for an insert, I set the current date in an asp textbox. When the user submits the form is when I get the cast exception. Would I try and set the sqldatasource insert parameter value? I have some other code that runs in the FormView ItemInserting event. Would that be the place for it?

Comment: @Ryan - posted update to answer, just realized you are using VB.NET so I converted my entire answer to use VB.NET instead of C#.

Comment: Still getting this: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I think it may have worked. I changed the type of my insert parameter to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dateTime;

DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, 
                       "dd/MM/yyyy", //you can specify any desired format here
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dateTime);
```